# Mongoose (MongoDB) - relationship doesn't stop a delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am quite new to MongoDB/Mongoose. 
in my webapp (express), I have the following mongoose model.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var visitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Study: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "study"},
    Site:  {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "site"},
    Subject: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "subject"},
    Phase: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "phase"},
    Visit_date: Date
},{ strict: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model("visit", visitSchema);
```

As you see above, Visits have relationships with other models such as subject.

But I was surprised when I saw my application did not throw an error when I deleted a subject that had visits attached to it. How does integrity work in MongoDB? Shouldn't that throw an error in a way RDBMS would? What's the equivalent here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: No it doesn't throw anything, In mongoDB we don't have anything like that.
It should be implemented by you if you want it.

Comment: Thanks Lucia. That means I would have to implement in my app logic (express in my case) to check if there are any visits for this subject and deny the delete operations.

Answer (score 1):

As mongoDB does not store the actual object but just a reference (hence the "ref" in the field-definition), there is nothing wrong with deleting this document.

As these references are only used for $lookups/populates() (say "left inner join"), it doesn't matter if the referenced object exists or not.

You can however populate a document and update the "hydrated" ref-fields and mongoose will also automatically update them for you.